# How to display 4 column in a row with component in Element UI

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, element-ui

I have a Card component and I want to display 4 of them in one row.

```
<template>
  <el-container>
    <el-main>
      <el-row>
        <el-col :xs="24" :sm="12" :md="6" :lg="6" :xl="4">
          <Card class="grid-content" />
        </el-col>
      </el-row>
    </el-main>
  </el-container>
</template>
```

So I created this view but it doesnt display right. It display 1 row in 1 column. So how can I display something like this?

```
<Card/><Card/><Card/><Card/>
<Card/><Card/><Card/><Card/>
<Card/><Card/><Card/><Card/>
<Card/><Card/><Card/><Card/>
```

Comment: If you want todo this you shoudn't rely on the grid system of element IU, But you should rely on either css-grid or flexbox (both css)